# ¿Por qué los datos se duplican cuando inserto un registro en MySQL.?

Tags: sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Cuando inserto datos en phpMyAdmin se duplican los mismos datos creando una fila más.

Esto es lo que inserto en sql pero en la tabla se guarda una fila mas con los mismos datos.

`` INSERT INTO `articulos` (`id_articulo`, `nombre`, `precio`, `cantidad`, `descripcion`, `imagen`, `id_marca`, `id_categoria`) VALUES (NULL, 'camisa', '4000', '10', 'camisas lacost ', 'camisas.jpg', '454531', '10102'); ``

Comment: Puedes añadir o especificar la forma en la que lo insertas

Comment: Puedes aportarnos tu código? Así podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Resulta raro que en la tabla articulos, el id_articulo se le inserte un NULL....

Comment: @Vicent cuando es auto incrementable no importa que sea null el id

Comment: lo raro es que cuando inserto los datos mediante un formulario que tengo conectado con la base (dichos datos se guardan bien y sin repetirse).

Comment: Entiendo que es clave primaria de la tabla, la clave primaria no acepta el valor NULL. Si es autoincrementable no lo insertes en el INSERT ya lo hace sin necesidad de especificarlo.

Comment: @Vicent sisi de hecho el valor null está puesto por el mismo motor, yo no le inserto ningun valor a la clave.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! O tu query se ejecuta dos veces, o hay un trigger que hace que todo se repita. Con tan poca informacion, es dificil ayudarte

Comment: @wilsoncabrera Podrías colocar una imagen de tu phpMyAdmin con las filas insertadas para ver los valores.